# block synchronize with 2 objects is not working

Tags: java, synchronized

I'm testing out a code where I have 2 methods and a statement in each method is synchronized.

```
private final Object obj1 = new Object();
private final Object obj2 = new Object();

public void method1(int result)
{
 //there's a loop to create delay

 synchronized (obj1){
   sum = sum + result;
 }

 //there's a loop to create delay

}


public void method2(int result)
{
  //there's a loop to create delay

 synchronized (obj2){
   sum = sum - result;
 }

 //there's a loop to create delay

}
```

What I'm basically doing is I add a result to sum then subtract the same amount then print the sum. So my initial and final amount should be constant.

The problem is I don't know why the final amount is not the same as initial amount when I use 2 diff objects as lock. HOWEVER it's constant when I use 'this' object as lock for both statements. But using 'this' as object didn't make execution time faster than using method synchronized.

I'm still new to synchronization concept so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify an object in the `synchronize` block, that object is used like a lock for that block: only one `synchronize` block can use a lock object at any time.

When you use two *different* objects as locks, they become two *different* locks: two threads can lock them both at the same time - one thread per lock. This explains the inconsistent results: two threads can grab two separate locks concurrently, and modify the `sum` concurrently, resulting in incorrect calculations.

You should use a single lock to protect a single resource from concurrent access. This is what happens when you use `this`; the same would happen if you used `obj1` or `obj2` in both `synchronize` blocks, except in this case a user of your object would not be able to cause your methods to block forever by synchronizing on your object, and intentionally not releasing the lock.

Comment: Can you explain why the time diff between method and block synchronize are not noticeable for this case? (I didn't down vote either)

Comment: Also, the advantage of using an internal object to lock on instead of `this` is that it cannot be acquired externally, which would block the operation. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I am apparently the downvoter.  I don't know why though as I actually upvoted the answer.  Please edit your answer so that I can rectify this.

Comment: @user977151 I've lost the context a little: could you clarify to which scenario does your "this case" refer, the two separate locks, or a single lock?

Comment: @user977151 There's no difference between a synchronized method and a method only containing a block synchronized on `this` because they're the same.

Comment: For single lock, I kind of thought it's faster because you're not synchronizing the whole method which is why im confused why the execution time for single lock or method synchronize is the same

Comment: @user977151 The timing is the same because a single lock and synchronized method is the same thing under the hood: synchronized method is a language shortcut to `synchronize(this) {...}` block.

Comment: @user977151 I missed your "loop" comments in your code sample. Beware of how you create delays, the JVM and its JIT compiler are smarter than you think, an empty loop or a loop incrementing a local variable which isn't use anywhere else could very well be eliminated by the JIT. If you want to introduce some delay, use `Thread.sleep()` or some significant code.

Answer (score 0):

Both `synchronized` blocks should be on same object(either `obj1` (or) `obj2`),  if you would like synchronize operations on `sum`.

Otherwise each thread acquires lock on one object and they can perform operations same time.

Each thread acquires a lock on object before executing any protected code. `T1` may acquire lock of `Obj1` and `T2` may acquire lock of `Obj2` same time and continue execution, which may give inconsistent results.